# How to detect more that one word in python string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was going through and example and it has this thing written " Check if their is more than one item in python string"

So how to check for multiple entries in string using **in** keyword?

Example:

```
items = input("Enter the name of items: ")
if "table" in items:
      print("Its a table")
           if "chair" in items:
               print("Its a chair")
```

This program will work smooth for the sentence having table and chair in it. Now what i want is to get the output like **"two or more items are entered"** if I Input **"table chair sofa"**

Comment: can you give some example.. only text would not work

Comment: Please check the edited code for Example

Comment: Do you mean sequentially or nested? For sequential you can use [if...elif...](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_if_else.htm)

Comment: What exactly is the criteria here? Are you perhaps after a simple count of the number of words? Or are you only to count specific items - "table" and "chair" for instance - if that's the case - how are you expected to handle entries other than those? Also, what about the input "tablet wheelchair"?

Comment: Well Its just I want to detect and give the appropriate message to user if he has entered more than two words in input. With the use of only if statement. I don't want to use else or in keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
items = 'table chair sofa'
words = items.split()
for word in words:
    print(word)
if (len(words)) > 1:
    print('two or more items entered')
```